# mongodb query return "none" as result

Tags: python, mongodb-query

the result should be:

```
'"timestamp:2017-01-01 00:00:00"'
```

but it returns `"none"`
where did I go wrong?

```
pipeline = [{"$match":{"timestamp":"2017-01-01 00:00:00"}}]
cursor=mycol.aggregate(pipeline)
result=low.append(cursor)
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the value of `low`?

Comment: Low is a empty list

Comment: Please include an example of what a document looks like

Answer (score 0):

the problem was on the mongo process.

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```